# Raster Calculator to extract elevation and slope conditions in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, raster-calculator

I've got a DEM ("ASTER_Nepal.tif") and a slope ("ASTER_Slope.tif") and am trying to create a new raster for elevation values between 2000 & 7000m and between 5 & 60 degree slope. I've tried to use the raster calculator but the expression escapes me and I cannot get it to work!

Comment: Can you include the expression that you have so far (that isn't working)? :)

Answer (score 3):

`Con(((ASTER_Nepal.tif > 2000) & (ASTER_Nepal.tif <7000)) & ((ASTER_Slope.tif >5) & (ASTER_Slope.tif<60)),1,0)`

It is however, advisable to change your tif files into ESRI grid before doing raster calculations. Also the above gives you a raster with value 1 for the conditions you set above and 0 if it doesn't meet the criteria. You can choose what values to give the true and false statement.